# Info on widget appearing when swiping up

Tags: android, material-design

Does anyone know the name of the "swiping up" widget in the home screen of an android phone?

I have seen this feature before with the google now swipe menu feature on your home screen, where you can swipe up on your device and a menu appears. I wanted to know if you can create your own. What is the name of this feature, if any, and is it possible to do in the first place? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phoenixstudios.aiogestures&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

From a design point of view, I believe you are referring to [bottom sheets](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html#). As you can see, it is a standardized pattern in the Material Design specs, though not-so-popular in my opinion.

As for the implementation, there is no `widget` (or `view`) that does exactly this thing. You should try implementing it on your own, taking care of swipes, entering animations and so on. [Official specs](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-sheets.html#bottom-sheets-specs) might help. If you are lucky enough, there could be some external library.

Example: https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet

Comment: No I'm talking about the google now swipe menu feature where on your home screen you can swipe up on your device and a menu appears. I wanted to know if you can create your own.

Comment: No problem. I suggest you to rephrase and edit your question to be more clear and get help from others :-)

Comment: An example of this would be: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phoenixstudios.aiogestures&hl=en